# password tag in struts2 not working properly

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts2. I have jsp with the fields `username`, `password`, `email`, `postal code` like this. I used  `<s:password>` tag for `password` field in input jsp. While submitting the page, if any errors in that page then redirecting the action to same input page. In this case the `password` field is cleared and other fields are there with entered values, but I want to show the `password` field with previously entered value instead of empty value. How?

Answer (score 7):

Set `showPassword` property to **true**.

```
<s:password key="password" showPassword="true" />
```